# getDate function in other language?

Tags: php, function, getdate

Is it possible to set the language of getDate function in another language? (e.g. Dutch)

I have tried to set locale with

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');
echo strftime('%e %B %Y om %H:%M',time());
```

but this doesn't change the language for me, it's still in english.

I use the getDate function as

```
<?php 
    $mydate=getdate(date("U"));
    echo "$mydate[weekday], $mydate[month] $mydate[mday], $mydate[year]";
?>
```

What is the easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use PHP's Internationalization extension (further is referred as Intl).

http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php allows to display date and time according to the localized format or given pattern or set of rules, and to parse strings into date and time.

Here's an example:

```
// create an instance by setting your locale
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'nl_NL',
     IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
     IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
// call the format function to get in string
echo $fmt->format(time());
```

Comment: I get an error as I use this method, saying the following:  Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found

Comment: Make sure you have PHP intl extension enabled on your server.

Comment: the extension is enabled

Comment: are you sure it's enabled? how did you check?